# Uneven line-spacing with xelatex and memoir

Tags: xetex, memoir, line-spacing, arabic, xepersian

My document uses the `memoir`-class and I compile it with `XeLaTeX`. It seems that the linespacing varies throughout the document. Here is a MWE that shows the issue:

```
\documentclass[14pt, extrafontsizes]{memoir}


\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\fontsize{18pt}{17pt}\selectfont

\noindent{یک احساس معمولاً  طرح یک  فکر تقویت شده و با انرژی را معرفی می کند، و به علت  شدت بار انرژی آن، اغلب در ابتدا به  حد کافی در لحظه حاضر بودن و نظاره  کردن آن آسان  نیست. احساس می خواهد  که به شما غلبه کند، و معمولاً موفق می شود، مگر این که حضور در شما به اندازه  کافی  وجود داشته باشد. اگر شما توسط  عدم حضور که معمول است، به طرف  شناسایی  شدن ناهوشیارانه با احساس  کشیده    شوید، آن احساس به طور موقت  " شما " می شود. اکثراً  بین فکر کردن  و احساس  شما یک  دایره  باطل  و شریر ساخته می شود:  آنها  یکدیگر  را تغذیه می کنند. طرح  فکر، یک  بازتاب  بزرگ  از خودش را به  شکل احساس بوجود می آورد و تناوب ارتعاشات آن احساس، طرح  فکر ابتدایی  را تغذیه  می کند. از طریق  ماندگار شدن ذهن  در موقعیت،  رویداد و یا  شخصی که علت بوجود آمدن آن احساس گردیده است،  فکر به احساس انرژی می دهد، که سپس احساس به نوبه خود به  طرح  فکری انرژی می دهد و این رَوند ادامه پیدا می کند.   }

     به طور اساسی، تمام احساسات تغییرات  در یک احساس اصلی  و متمایز نشده می باشند، احساسی که  مبداً  آن، از عدم آگاهی  شما نسبت به این  مطلب که شما فراتر از اسم  و فرم چه هستید می باشد. به علت یکسان بودن  ماهیت آن،  پیدا  کردن  نامی  برای  توصیف  دقیق  این احساس سخت است. "ترس"  می تواند به آن نزدیک باشد، اما جدا از حس تهدید مداوم، ترس شامل یک حس عمیق  از تَرک شدن  و تکمیل  نبودن نیز می باشد. شاید بهتر باشد اصطلاحی  را بکار ببریم  که مانند آن احساس اصلی، متمایز نشده است و به سادگی آن را "درد" نام ببریم. یکی  از وظایف اصلی  ذهن، جنگیدن  یا رفع  کردن آن درد احساسی است، که خود دلیلی برای  فعالیت پی در پی ذهن می باشد، اما همواره به تنها چیزی که می تواند دست بیابد پوشش  موقتی  آن است. در حقیقت، هر اندازه که ذهن برای خلاص شدن از شر "درد"  سخت تر مبارزه کند، درد بیشتر می شود. ذهن نه هرگز می تواند راه حلی  پیدا کند ، و نه  به شما اجازه پیدا کردن راه حلی  را می دهد،  به این دلیل که  آن  خودش ذاتاً  بخشی  از "مشکل" است.  تصور کنید  یک  رئیس  پلیس  سعی برای پیدا کردن فردی که عمداً ایجاد حریق میکند دارد، در حالی که آن فرد خود رئیس پلیس است. شما تا زمانی که حس  شناسایی  خویش  با ذهن را متوقف  نسازید، از آن درد رها نخواهید  شد،  یا می شود گفت  شناسایی شدن با نفْس را، بنابراین  ذهن  از  مرحله   قدرت  خویش واژگون می شود و هستی به عنوان طبیعت واقعی شما خودش را آشکار می سازد.

  بله، من می دانم شما چه سوالی دارید.

\end{document}
```

This example shows that the spacing in the middle of the page is very narrow (red rectangle), and it is followed by a fairly wide whitespace before the new paragraph begins.

[image]

I tried to fix the linespacing manually by `\linespread{1.0}`, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Well, using less interline skip than the font size is a sure recipe for getting uneven line spacing.

Comment: @egreg Even if I use (e.g.) `\fontsize{16pt}{30pt}\selectfont` there is a wide gap between the first and second paragraph

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

First problem: the baseline skip you use is too small (17pt) and some adjacent lines don't fit this because of ascenders and descenders. Look at lines 5 and 6 in your image.

Second problem: the text height doesn't contain an integer number of lines and `memoir` tries to fill a page. The only place it can get extensible space is between the two paragraphs, but you get an “Underfull `vbox`” message when running XeLaTeX.

Either you fix the text height or use `\raggedbottom`.

```
\documentclass[17pt, extrafontsizes]{memoir}

\usepackage[logo=off]{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
%\sloppy
\raggedbottom

\fontsize{18pt}{24pt}\selectfont

\noindent
یک احساس معمولاً  طرح یک  فکر تقویت شده و با انرژی را معرفی می کند، و به علت  شدت بار انرژی آن، اغلب در ابتدا به  حد کافی در لحظه حاضر بودن و نظاره  کردن آن آسان  نیست. احساس می خواهد  که به شما غلبه کند، و معمولاً موفق می شود، مگر این که حضور در شما به اندازه  کافی  وجود داشته باشد. اگر شما توسط  عدم حضور که معمول است، به طرف  شناسایی  شدن ناهوشیارانه با احساس  کشیده    شوید، آن احساس به طور موقت  " شما " می شود. اکثراً  بین فکر کردن  و احساس  شما یک  دایره  باطل  و شریر ساخته می شود:  آنها  یکدیگر  را تغذیه می کنند. طرح  فکر، یک  بازتاب  بزرگ  از خودش را به  شکل احساس بوجود می آورد و تناوب ارتعاشات آن احساس، طرح  فکر ابتدایی  را تغذیه  می کند. از طریق  ماندگار شدن ذهن  در موقعیت،  رویداد و یا  شخصی که علت بوجود آمدن آن احساس گردیده است،  فکر به احساس انرژی می دهد، که سپس احساس به نوبه خود به  طرح  فکری انرژی می دهد و این رَوند ادامه پیدا می کند.   

     به طور اساسی، تمام احساسات تغییرات  در یک احساس اصلی  و متمایز نشده می باشند، احساسی که  مبداً  آن، از عدم آگاهی  شما نسبت به این  مطلب که شما فراتر از اسم  و فرم چه هستید می باشد. به علت یکسان بودن  ماهیت آن،  پیدا  کردن  نامی  برای  توصیف  دقیق  این احساس سخت است. "ترس"  می تواند به آن نزدیک باشد، اما جدا از حس تهدید مداوم، ترس شامل یک حس عمیق  از تَرک شدن  و تکمیل  نبودن نیز می باشد. شاید بهتر باشد اصطلاحی  را بکار ببریم  که مانند آن احساس اصلی، متمایز نشده است و به سادگی آن را "درد" نام ببریم. یکی  از وظایف اصلی  ذهن، جنگیدن  یا رفع  کردن آن درد احساسی است، که خود دلیلی برای  فعالیت پی در پی ذهن می باشد، اما همواره به تنها چیزی که می تواند دست بیابد پوشش  موقتی  آن است. در حقیقت، هر اندازه که ذهن برای خلاص شدن از شر "درد"  سخت تر مبارزه کند، درد بیشتر می شود. ذهن نه هرگز می تواند راه حلی  پیدا کند ، و نه  به شما اجازه پیدا کردن راه حلی  را می دهد،  به این دلیل که  آن  خودش ذاتاً  بخشی  از "مشکل" است.  تصور کنید  یک  رئیس  پلیس  سعی برای پیدا کردن فردی که عمداً ایجاد حریق میکند دارد، در حالی که آن فرد خود رئیس پلیس است. شما تا زمانی که حس  شناسایی  خویش  با ذهن را متوقف  نسازید، از آن درد رها نخواهید  شد،  یا می شود گفت  شناسایی شدن با نفْس را، بنابراین  ذهن  از  مرحله   قدرت  خویش واژگون می شود و هستی به عنوان طبیعت واقعی شما خودش را آشکار می سازد.

  بله، من می دانم شما چه سوالی دارید.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I removed the useless group; `\noindent` is not a command with an argument.